# How to add reloadData to Xcode default Master-Detail Tableview application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created the master-detail view app using xcode and let xcode generate all the things it should do. I added a few buttons to the TableView and finally hooked up a responder method to these buttons: looking something like this (not all code pasted):

```
-(IBAction)orderBy:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

int lv_temp = sender.tag;
choice = lv_temp;


switch (lv_temp) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        //This gives us all the different sections available.
            typeSections = [Items valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.type"];

//Do some more stuff and create the Dictionary so we hold an array with a key for each section
            [ItemsByType2 setObject:ItemsTemp forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", id]];
            [ItemsTemp removeAllObjects];

 }
```

The end result is that I finally have a NSDictionary object containing arrays with the section ID's as a key. I'd like to reload these sections so we have a kind of sorting.

The problem is, how and where to call the reloadData of the generated tableView? Looks like the tableView itself is not accessible in the Sender method (which sounds kind of logical to me btw) but I do not know how to call the method so the tableView will call it's methods numberOfSections, RowsPerSection etc (pseudocode btw).

Any ideas?

Cheers!
Laurens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)orderBy:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
 int lv_temp = sender.tag;
 choice = lv_temp;

 switch (lv_temp) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1: {

        //This gives us all the different sections available.
        typeSections = [Items valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.type"];

        //Do some more stuff and create the Dictionary so we hold an array with a key for each section
        [ItemsByType2 setObject:ItemsTemp forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", id]];
        [ItemsTemp removeAllObjects];

        }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: I discovered this myself as well :-( How could I have missed this?!?! Thanks Retro!